# using a Linked List with a Stack: private acces in node error

Tags: java, node.js, linked-list, stack

I keep getting the x and next have a private access in Node. I tried playing around and keep getting the same error no matter what I switch around in both my Node class and my Linked List class. I have my node saved in a different file and it looks like so:
``

```html
public class Node{
 private Node next;
 private String name;
 private int ssn;
 private int key;

 public Node(String name, int ssn){
  this.name = name;
  this.ssn = ssn;
 }

 public void setNext(Node n){
  this.next = next;
 }

 public int getSSN(){
  return this.ssn;
 }
 
 public int getKey(){
  return ssn%10000;
 }
 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }
 
 public Node getNext(){
  return this.next;
 }

 public void setSSN(int ssn){
  this.ssn= ssn;
 }
```

and then I have my Linked List stack code which looks like this:

```html
public class StackLL{
 private Node head; //Whatever is on top of the stack
 private int n; //Suze of the stack
 private Node next;
 
 public StackLL(){
  head = null;
  n = 0;
 }
 

 public boolean isEmpty(){
  return n == 0;
 }
  
 public void push(){
  Node temp = head;
  head = new Node();
  head.x = x;
  Node head.next = temp;
  n++;
 }
 
 public Node pop(){
  Node x = head.x;
  head = head.next;
  n--;
  return x;
 }
  
 public Node top(){
  return head.x;
 }
 
 // printStack method for StackLL
 public void printStack() {
  System.out.println(n);
  Node temp = head;
  while (temp != null) {
  System.out.println(temp.getKey());
  temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted comments in your code about the issues I saw. In the `Node` class there was only a single one, in `setNext()`:

```
public void setNext(Node n){
    // assign the parameter to the field
    this.next = n;
}
```

There were a number in the `StackLL` class:

```
public class StackLL{
    private Node head; //Whatever is on top of the stack
    private int n; //Suze of the stack
    // the field next is not used; just delete it
//  private Node next;

    public StackLL(){
        head = null;
        n = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return n == 0;
    }

    public void push(){
        Node temp = head;
        // The Node constructor takes two arguments
        head = new Node("Jim", 541365250);
        // x is not defined; delete this statement
//      head.x = x;
        // Node.next is not visible (it’s private), so use the setter 
        head.setNext(temp);
        n++;
    }

    public Node pop(){
        // if you want to return a Node, just return head
        Node x = head;
        // next is private, use the getter
        head = head.getNext();
        n--;
        return x;
    }

    public Node top(){
        // if you want to return a Node, just return head
        return head;
    }

    // printStack method for StackLL
    public void printStack() {
        System.out.println(n);
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
        System.out.println(temp.getKey());
        temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    }

}
```

Except for the local variable in `pop()` I found no `x`, so I removed or changed references to it. Returning Node instances that are still linked to other nodes would not be a good idea in production code, but I have let it be for now.